# AWS Glue Schema Registry Java Client to register, update versions of the schemas

Tags: java, schema, aws-glue

Does AWS Java SDK provide any means to interact with Glue schema registry? I am looking for methods such as registering a schema, updating the version of already registered schema, deleting schema. I know aws provides Python library method as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-schema-registry-api.html#aws-glue-api-schema-registry-api-CreateRegistry)

I am looking for Java ways to interact with registry. Similar to [Spring Cloud Schema Registry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-schema-registry/docs/1.1.3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-schema-registry.html#_schema_registry_client)

AWS Glues also provides [endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glue.html) but I am not sure if they let me interact with glue schema registry.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930551/using-aws-glue-schema-registry-with-confluent-serde-clients) suggests to follow the [examples provided by aws](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry) but I am looking specifically for ways to interact with AWS Glue Schema registry using Java

Would it be better to wrap Java code around python based API provided by AWS ?

Any thoughts or guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS Glue SDK for Java to interact with Glue Schema Registry APIs. [Ref](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/glue/GlueClient.html).